Does the Democratic Party have an alternative nominee to Joe Biden?
From what I understand, Joe Biden is the presumptive Democratic presidential nominee. The Democratic Party will formally name its nominee this August at the Democratic National Convention in Chicago.
With the increasing calls for Biden to drop out of the presidential race, does the Democratic Party have an alternative nominee to Joe Biden?

Well, this question got rather overtaken by events.
The presumptive alternative to Biden is Vice President Kamala Harris. This is confirmed by Biden's endorsement of Harris.
